# PIC18 How to make the dot move on a 8x8 matrix display?

Tags: pic, xor, microchip, mplab

I am trying to make a dot move up and down an 8x8 matrix display of column `RA1`. I use switches on a microcontroller to make the dot to move Up(`RB5`) and Down (`RB0`). I have the dot start in the position 0x08. The code works fine but the dot moves down when both switches are on. I was thinking that something like XORWF would help? Any ideas?

```
     #include "p18F4520.inc"
        ;:::::CONFIG::::::::::::::::::::::::    
            CONFIG OSC = HS
            CONFIG PWRT = OFF
            CONFIG WDT = OFF
            CONFIG PBADEN = OFF
            CONFIG LVP = OFF

            org 0x000000
        PORST   GOTO MAIN

            org 0x000020
        ;:::::DELAY:::::::::::::::::::::::::    
        IDSHORT equ 0x20           
        IDLONG  equ 0x21          
        ED10MS  CLRF IDSHORT      
            MOVLW 0XFF
            MOVWF IDLONG
        LDLOOP  DECFSZ IDSHORT      
            GOTO LDLOOP     
            DECFSZ IDLONG
            GOTO LDLOOP
            RETURN
        ;:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    MAIN    CLRF    TRISD
            CLRF    PORTD
            CLRF    TRISA 
            CLRF    PORTA
            BCF     PORTA,RA1
            BSF     PORTA,RA1
            SETF    TRISB
            MOVLW   0X08
            MOVWF   PORTD


    LOOP    BSF     PORTA,RA1
            CALL    ED10MS
            BCF     PORTA,RA1

            BTFSS   PORTB,RB0 ;CHECKS IF SWHITCH IS ON - MOVE DOWN IF TRUE
            GOTO    DOWN
            BTFSS   PORTB,RB5 ;CHECKS IF SWHITCH IS ON - MOVE UP IF TRUE
            GOTO    UP

            GOTO    LOOP

    UP      MOVLW   0X80
            CPFSEQ  PORTD,W ;CHECKS IF IT REACHED THE TOP
            RLNCF   PORTD
            GOTO    LOOP

    DOWN    MOVLW   0X01
            CPFSEQ  PORTD,W ;CHECKS ID IT REACHED THE BOTTOM
            RRNCF   PORTD
            GOTO    LOOP


        END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the bits in the PORTB reg and use XORLW. If all your other bits on PORTB are zero, ignore the ANDLW. If not, clear the other bits (other than RB0 and RB5) by using the ANDLW line. In LOOP, replace your bit tests with this. Whenever your switches are either both off or both on, this code will simply fall through and loop. STATUS and Z should be defined in the INC file, but you'll define TEMP. Note, this will work on one "snapshot" of PORTB, if you will. And this maintains your use of GOTOs for UP and DOWN:

```
MOVF   PORTB,W        ; put PORTB bits in w
ANDLW  b'00100001'    ; clr unused bits
MOVWF  TEMP           ; save w in TEMP

XORLW  0X20           ; look for RB0 'on', RB5 'off'
BTFSC  STATUS,Z       ; if untrue, Z bit clr, skip
GOTO   DOWN           ; if true, goto DOWN

MOVF   TEMP,W         ; get saved copy of PORTB bits

XORLW  0X01           ; look for RB0 'off', RB5 'on'
BTFSC  STATUS,Z       ; if untrue, Z bit clr, skip
GOTO   UP             ; if true, goto UP

GOTO   LOOP           ; any other case, goto LOOP
```